# using difftime in R from one column

Tags: r, difference, difftime

Hello can you help me with difference in (hours) in R from one column.
I use only basic package R. I would like to create new column with hours 
so the column look like

```
hours<-c(0,24,23,21,31,26,28)

time<-c('10. 4. 2018 10:16:11', 
'11. 4. 2018 10:16:15', 
'12. 4. 2018 10:13:31',
'13. 4. 2018 8:16:31', 
'14. 4. 2018 15:16:21',
'15. 4. 2018 17:16:31', 
'16. 4. 2018 19:15:31')
```

I have one colum (time) and i would like to create new column (hours)

thanks

Comment: Can post the output of `dput(time)`, please?

Comment: `difftime` requires `time1` and `time2`. How do you use that only one column?

Comment: something like `diff(as.POSIXct(time, format = '%d. %m. %Y %H:%M:%S'))`

Comment: sorry no difftime but difference in column

Comment: second row difference first row , third row difference second row .... etc

Comment: @Rui Barradas  you know ?

Comment: Try `c(0, difftime(time[-1], time[-length(time)]))`. Then `round` the result.

Answer (score 1):

Enhancing [Sotos' approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53870640/using-difftime-in-r-from-one-column#comment94588540_53870640),

```
c(0, round(diff(as.POSIXct(time, format = '%d. %m. %Y %H:%M:%S'), units = "hours")))
```

comes close to OP's expected result

> ```
> [1]  0 24 24 22 31 26 26
> ```

#### Data

```
time <- c(
  '10. 4. 2018 10:16:11',
  '11. 4. 2018 10:16:15',
  '12. 4. 2018 10:13:31',
  '13. 4. 2018 8:16:31',
  '14. 4. 2018 15:16:21',
  '15. 4. 2018 17:16:31',
  '16. 4. 2018 19:15:31'
)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the issue. This is R code.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is the following.

First coerce to class `POSIXct`.

```
time <- as.POSIXct(time, format = "%d. %m. %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Now use `difftime`, it will give the result in the required units.

```
c(0, difftime(time[-1], time[-length(time)]))
#[1]  0.00000 24.00111 23.95444 22.05000 30.99722 26.00278 25.98333
```

The rounded output is simple to obtain.

```
round(c(0, difftime(time[-1], time[-length(time)])))
#[1]  0 24 24 22 31 26 26
```